# Can I ask in Stack Overflow a question which doesn't get any answer from other Stack Exchange sites with low traffic?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I asked a question in webmasters.stackexchange.com, < [see question here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48515/cant-delete-a-site-from-google-website-translator) >

But when I checked the chat, it seems the last activity was since 2 days ago. Therefore I thought that webmasters.stackexchange.com has considerably low traffic vs SO.

Is it okay to ask in SO the same question, hoping someone here would answer the same question?

Comment: Is the question *on-topic* on Stack Overflow??? If not, then it should be obvious that the answer is no.

Comment: Is my question not a valid question? How come there are 4 downvotes with no comments whatsoever? I just want to undetstand why. Thx

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences In this case I assume some users downvoted to indicate that your question should not be asked on SO.

Comment: but SO is different from meta, right? i know this should not be asked on the main SO site.. but why not here?

Comment: and on your link it says i can ask if the question is about SO or Stack Exchange.. as the question clearly indicates.. it is a question on usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this specific case, no. That question is on-topic on Webmasters and would be off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Your best bet is to bump the question by adding details and fixing punctuation, grammar, capitalization, etc.  If that doesn't work, you can post a bounty.

In general, if your question is on-topic on both sites, please flag for a moderator to migrate it to the other site instead of posting a cross-site duplicate.

Comment: Ok thx. But can i ask, why is my question bad enough to be downvoted. Is it the formatting or something? Thanks again

Comment: @reikyoushin No, I don't think there's anything wrong with the formatting of your question. People on Meta tend to downvote things that they disagree with, or when people suggest something that you shouldn't do.  I think the downvotes in this case just mean "no, don't cross-post that question."

Comment: ok, but if unlike SO people use it on META that way, shouldn't it 'not' affect the rep score if its only used to agree or disagree and not to grade the question?

Answer (score 6):

The Webmasters site *does* see less traffic than Stack Overflow. Many sites do. However, you only asked your question an hour ago. A little patience, please. :)

That said, this question would be off-topic on Stack Overflow, so you'd be more likely to get downvotes and have your question closed than you would be to get a faster answer.

Comment: OP says last activity was 2 days ago?

Comment: @djechlin "but when i checked **the chat**, it seems the last activity was since 2 days ago." (emphasis mine) If you look at the front page, you'll see plenty of recent activity.

Comment: Yeah i saw new questions but when i looked for people on chat i saw last activity was 2 days ago. I asked this question not specifically for this instance but if i come up with another question so i would know if its ok to just put it in SO instead.. take note, not this question but those that would come in the future..

Comment: And yes i know i need to be patient. I asked this for future questions.. i can wait for other people to answer my question. But since i noticed that there is low traffic on wm.se if i wondered if i could consider asking in so instead

Answer (score 1):

No.  That question will be closed as off topic.

There are some questions that are arguably appropriate for two sites, e.g. often bash scripting questions can wind up on SO or serverfault.  In that case, I suppose you could flag and make the case to a moderator to try moving it, *provided it's on topic both places.*  I don't know what a moderator would do here.